# Using required with a custom search/dropdown control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, user-controls

**How do I enforce form requirement and validation on a custom form control in which the required data is not in a regular control?**

[image]

I am using a custom user control called a Search and Select which can be found [here](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-search-and-select), and although useful, it lacks some validation functionality.  The control allows the user to do a typeahead search by typing into a textfield **(#1)**, which then modifies a dropdown **(#2)**.  When an item in the dropdown **(#3)** is clicked, it becomes selected, causing the name of the item to also be displayed at the top **(#4)** and to have a checkmark displayed next to it in the dropdown list.

**How can I enforce that an item has been selected on this control?**  Information that I've found on forcing the usage of `require`/`ngRequire` for custom controls comprised of other controls within it involve propagating the requireness of one of those inner controls - for example, making the whole Search control use the required status of the textbox contained within.  However, this would be inaccurate - what is in the textbox is irrelevant, and whether something is selected is **actually a matter of whether a behind-the-scenes local variable is set** and whether its name is displayed in raw text.

[image]

I have attempted to modify the directive by requiring ngModel and modifying `ngModel.$isEmpty`.  However, this does not appear to have any effect.

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

    ...

    ngModel.$isEmpty = function(value) {
        return (!scope.selectedItem || scope.selectedItem === {})
    };

    ...

}
```

**How can I force the requiredness of this field to be based off of the value of `scope.selectItem`?**

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr, or JSbin, or Codepen of what you have tried already? It will make it easier for us to answer your question

Comment: @JoelCDoyle Since the code is tied into and surrounded by other proprietary, company code owned by my employer, I cannot give much more specifics.  In any case, I believe my question is relatively generic - it doesn't even actually require the usage of the particular Search control I mention, which is only an example.